# Getting specific raw elements and its subelements from XML file using XML::TWIG?

Tags: perl, xml-parsing

I have the following large xml file (5-10gb) :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<catalog>
   <book id="bk101">
      <author>Gambardella, Matthew</author>
      <title>XML Developer's Guide</title>
      <genre>Computer</genre>
      <price>44.95</price>          
   </book>
   <car id="bk102">
      <author>Ralls, Kim</author>
      <title>Midnight Rain</title>
      <genre>Fantasy</genre>
      <price>5.95</price>
   </car>
   <book id="bk101">
      <author>Joseph</author>
      <title>XML Developer's Guide</title>
      <genre>Computer</genre>
   </book>
   <magazine id="bk103">
      <author>Gambardella, Matthew</author>
      <title>Maeve Ascendant</title>
      <genre>Fantasy</genre>
   </magazine>
   .....
</catalog>
```

How can i read from book and magazine elements (ignore car) but only extract the the element (whole block) that contains the author name Gambardella, Matthew to a new file using XML TWIG or any other method in PERL?

```
   <book id="bk101">
      <author>Gambardella, Matthew</author>
      <title>XML Developer's Guide</title>
      <genre>Computer</genre>
      <price>44.95</price>          
   </book>      
   <magazine id="bk103">
      <author>Gambardella, Matthew</author>
      <title>Maeve Ascendant</title>
      <genre>Fantasy</genre>
   </magazine>
   .....
</catalog>
```

Answer (score 0):

The script expects the XML file as command line argument and will get rid of all elements that do not match the `$criteria`. You also should consider to split up the input file into smaller chunks to avoid `out of memory` issues.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use warnings FATAL => 'all';
use strict;
use XML::Twig;

my $criteria = 'Gambardella, Matthew';
my $xml  = XML::Twig->new(
  twig_handlers => {
    'catalog/*' => \&catalog,
  },
  pretty_print => 'indented',
)->parsefile($ARGV[0]);

print $xml->toString();

sub catalog {
  my ($t, $catalog) = @_;

  $catalog->cut() unless $catalog->findvalue('author') eq $criteria;

  return;
}
```